# Why `functions.https.HttpsError` is not shown in the Firebase function logs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, error-logging

I'm throwing an error from my callable Firebase function:

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        `Invalid token ${token} for file ${fileName}.`
      );
```

I the logs I see only the following:

```
12:29:22.500 PM SQR-cancelAllotment Function execution took 1779 ms, finished with status code: 400
12:29:20.722 PM SQR-cancelAllotment Function execution started
```

So, code `400` is indicated without any error message. Why?

I wouldn’t like to duplicate the error message in a separate `console.error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an HttpsError is a signal to the client that the function didn't work as expected.  It's not an indication that the function terminated with a crash (which would be logged).  When you throw an HttpsError, if you want to see a message in the log, you should also make a call to `console.error()` (or whatever log level you want) in order for that to show up.

Comment: Thank you. So is it be design of `HttpsError`? Still for me it would be logical if after `finished with status code: 400` the actual message would be shown. Is it worth a feature request?

Comment: You are always welcome to file a feature request. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

For throwing errors in Cloud Functions you could use the [Stackdriver Error Reporting client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs)

Here you can find the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/nodejs) for setting up the error reporting ( you have some examples there,also)

Comment: Thank you Andrei, however `console.error` is enough for logging from a function. My question is why the `HttpsError` message is not logged automatically.

Comment: I understand. Because it is not an actual error or crush in the Cloud Functions system to be logged. It is something more or less intended, let's say.